# Storing data in multiple sessions

Tags: php, session

Hi what I'm trying to do is put all 5 of the file id's into sessions so I can later move the according physical file names. the $sid sessionID will be the same for each, the query pulls the unique $data[Id]. The limit is set to 5, how do I make sure each session gets a unique data[Id] from the results and if there is only 3 result don't use the last 2...

```
    $results = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM test WHERE Language = '".$lang."' ORDER BY id DESC, CreationDate DESC LIMIT $start, 5");

    while ($data = mysql_fetch_array($results)) {
        $Record_Count = $Record_Count + 1;

session_start();
$sid = session_id();

        unset($_SESSION['file_1'], $file_1);
    $_SESSION['file_1'] = $sid . '-' . $data[Id] . '-slow'; 
        unset($_SESSION['file_2'], $file_2);
    $_SESSION['file_2'] = $sid . '-' . $data[Id] . '-slow'; 
        unset($_SESSION['file_3'], $file_3);
    $_SESSION['file_3'] = $sid . '-' . $data[Id] . '-slow'; 
        unset($_SESSION['file_4'], $file_4);
    $_SESSION['file_4'] = $sid . '-' . $data[Id] . '-slow'; 
        unset($_SESSION['file_5'], $file_5);
    $_SESSION['file_5'] = $sid . '-' . $data[Id] . '-slow'; 

        }
```

Comment: You should quote the `Id` in `$data[Id]`: `$data['Id']`.

Comment: if i did the example below using a  2 dimension array like : $_SESSION['files'][] how would I call up each entry would a simple echo $_SESSION['files'][2] work?

Answer (score 1):

You can only have one session running at a time.

To make sure there's only three results, put the collected IDs in an array and test its length.

```
if(count($collectedIDs) != 3) { $collectedIDs[] = $newID; }
```

Answer (score 1):

use 2 dimension array like :  `$_SESSION['files'][]`

```
session_start();
$sid = session_id();
unset($_SESSION['files']);
$Record_Count = 0;
while ($data = mysql_fetch_array($results) && $Record_Count < 5) {
      $Record_Count = $Record_Count + 1; 
      $_SESSION['files'][] = $sid . '-' . $data[Id] . '-slow'; 
}
```

Comment: how would i retrieve all the names from within the $_SESSION['files']

i'm assuming it would be something like this, but it would have to cycle through all the array entry... but how? 

    $scrtmp = $_SESSION['files'];
    if (file_exists($scrtmp)) {
    @copy("/temp/" . $scrtmp ,"/items/" . date(Y) . "/" . date(m) . "/" . $scrtmp);
}